# Are Lie algebras $u_n$ and $su_n$ simple?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I think, that $u_n$ isn't simple, because, for example, any matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
ia & 0 \\
0 & ia 
\end{pmatrix} \in Z(u_n)$, and hence $u_n$ has non-trivial ideal.
But i don't know anything about $su_n$.

Answer (score 6):

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is indeed simple, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group. And yes, the unitary Lie algebra $\mathfrak{u}(n)$  has a $1$-dimensional abelian center, so that it is not even semisimple.

Comment: Ok, but how prove it?

Comment: Assume that the Lie algebra has a non-trivial ideal $I$, and $x\in I$. Applying Lie brackets to $x$, show that every basis vector lies in the ideal (see also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123285/how-to-prove-the-lie-algebra-of-n-times-n-traceless-matrices-is-semi-simple)